# does req.cookies and req.session has same parameter? how do you access json?

Tags: json, node.js, session, cookies, express

```
if (!req.session.cart) { 
            req.session.cart = {
                styles: styles,
                count: 0,
                total: 0
            };
        }

        if (!req.session.cart.styles[product]) {

            req.session.cart.styles[product] = {
                "_id": style._id,
                "a": style.a,
                "color": color,
                "price": style.price,
                "category": style.category,
                "quantity": 1
             };

        }
```

here i have working cart session, since session eats too much memory i decided to try with cookies.

i tried exactly same format but req.session instead req.cookies = not working.

so what i did was

```
res.cookie("cart", "_id": style._id,
                "a": style.a,
                "color": color,
                "price": style.price,
                "category": style.category,
                "quantity": 1)
```

this works, but i don't have access to any other fields. how can i gain access to my json like session with cookie?

i need to create a format like above session.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie with any *string* you like. So stringify your json before setting it to a cookie.

```
res.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify({ 
   _id   : style._id,
   a     : style.a,
   color : color,
   // ...
}));
```

Then when it's time to use it, just unstringify it via `JSON.parse`

Comment: yes, but i need to have "styles" inside the cart. please see the first block

Comment: well, just wrap that into an array and stringify that! `styles = [{...}, {...}]; styles.push(...); res.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify(styles));`

Comment: so its res.cookie? not req.coookies?

Comment: req.cookies = an object full of request cookies;
res.cookie() = a function that sets a 'set-cookie' header sent with response.

Comment: ok, i have got something working but, it seems like 'products[product]' method does not work 'res.cookie'. any idea?